# UseState will not Update to Array on First Change

Tags: react-native, use-state

I am working in React Native and have encountered this numerous times, and it is extremely frustrating, and I know there has to be an easier solution that the hoops I've been jumping through.

Essentially whenever I have something like this

```
const [arrayState, setArrayState] = useState(false)
// OR //
const [arrayState, setArrayState] = useState([])
```

if I have a function that adds something to that array, it will not work on the first firing of that function, but will work subsequently. For example, the latest instance of this is when I am attempting to append image uri's to an initially empty local state array.

```
const [images, setImages] = useState(false)
// I have also tried '' '' = useState([]) //

// Other Code //
const handleClickTakePicture = async () => {
            const r = await takePhoto()
            if (!r.cancelled) {
                if (!images){
                    console.log("Should set images to ", [r.uri])
                    let temp = [r.uri]
                    setImages(temp)
                }
                else{
                    setImages([...images, r.uri]) 
                    changeFunction({
                        ...changeValue,
                        specific_pictures: images
                    })
                }
            }
        }
```

If I click the 'take picture' button 5 times, four picture uri's will be added the the `images` array. If I click it once, nothing will.
Why is this? I've noticed it can have similar issues when changing or setting hashes

EDIT: Added `takePhoto` function

```
const takePhoto = async () => {
    if (cameraRef) {
        try {
            let photo = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync({
                allowsEditing: true,
                aspect: [4, 3],
                // base64: true,
                quality: 1
            })
            return photo
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`useState` is an async function, meaning the state change will not be reflected immediately.

Instead, you can run the function everytime `setImages` is done with updating.

```
useEffect(()=>{
     changeFunction({
         ...changeValue,
         specific_pictures: images
     })
}, [images]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
...
                else{
                    setImages([...images, r.uri]) 
                    changeFunction({
                        ...changeValue,
                        specific_pictures: [...images, r.uri] //fix here
                    })
                }
...
```

Keep in mind the second parameter of useState is an asynchronous function, `setImages([...images, r.uri])` will be called before `changeFunction` but it will execute after `changeFunction`.

More details: [How JavaScript works](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-does-javascript-actually-work-part-1-b0bacc073cf)

Answer (score 0):

This is my fault for not specifying, but I had also tried @sid's solution. That also didn't work, but I did find some odd syntax that got the job done, although I do not know why it does and I would be very open to an explanation.

This does **NOT** work

```
const handleClickTakePicture = async () => {
    const r = await takePhoto()
    if (!r.cancelled) {
        if (!images){
            console.log("Should set images to ", [r.uri])
            let temp = [r.uri]
            setImages(temp)
        }
        else{
            setImages([...images, r.uri]) 
            changeFunction({
                ...changeValue,
                specific_pictures: images
            })
        }
    }
}
```

This **DOES** work

```
const handleClickTakePicture = async () => {
    const r = await takePhoto()
    if (!r.cancelled) {
         setImages(images => [...images, r.uri]) 
         changeFunction({
             ...changeValue,
             specific_pictures: images
         })
     } 
}
```

Comment: does adding `images =>` somehow circumvent the async nature of this process? The async aspects of JavaScript tend to allude my understanding far too often